# How to use Like,In on same column or field at same time using spring boot data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

What I want to do is look into the list which I can do By Using In operator but i want to use like  % operator to match whether the string contains that particular part

```
Example Db

Records

Id    tags     date

1     d,       ...

2     d1,d,    ...

3     d2,          ...
```

and the query that i want to fire is tags that contain d1,d and these d1 and d are diffrent strings not same its list of values that i will pass

But when i try to use Like and In both they give

```
My Jpa query

Jpa->   
 Page<Blog> findByTagsInLike(List<String> tags, Pageable page);


Error->
        ... 42 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property in found for type String! Traversed path: Blog.tags.
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.
```

Even if i change the position of Like and In still same error No property found its like after i can not use In

and this error ocurs on running

Comment: is your field `tags` only one field and is it string?

Comment: yes It is string problem is that I can not use Like and In both

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have a separate `tag` table to save all your tags and you should use then N-to-N relationship ta connect tags with a blog.
Secondly, your `tags` field is `String` and when you connect your Java Object attribute to this field, you should do it as `String tags`. That means it is not a `List`. So you cannot use it like `findByTagsInLike` because it is not a `List`, it is `String`.
What can you do is change your query method in the JPA repository:

```
List<Blog> findByTagsLike(String tags, Pageable page);
```

And to use this function you should pass something like this:

```
blogRepository.findByTagsLike("%d1,d%", ...); // Keep in mind that this method returns `List` of all `Blog` with given `like` operation.
```

Now, you need some method to construct your tags `like` operation expression, that you can write on your own.

Comment: No brother even if it is string still i can use list to check in and just now i tried it worked the problrm is that i can not use like operator with this.Below query works fine 

 Page<Blog> findByTagsIn(List<String> tags, Pageable page);